# Getting id of collapsible div in Jquery and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have multiple(it can be 100+) collapsible div (using bootstrap)

```
<div>
    <a href="#id1" data-toggle="collapse">
       <div class="col-lg-12">Title</div>
       <div class="image">Image</div>
    </a>
    <div id="id1" class="collapse">
       <div class="col-lg-12">Description</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#id2" data-toggle="collapse">
       <div class="col-lg-12">Title</div>
       <div class="image">Image</div>
    </a>
    <div id="id2" class="collapse">
       <div class="col-lg-12">Description</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And have **Jquery**

```
$('#id1').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
            $(".image").addClass('hidden');
        });

$('#id1').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
        $(".image").removeClass('hidden');
    });
```

I want to add `hidden` class on `show.bs.collapse`(this is from bootstrap) and remove `hidden` class on `hidden.bs.collapse'`With the jq code above I can do this just with one div that has `id1`. But how can I do this independently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id refers to one element on the DOM therefore you should use classes instead. Therefore you should select divs based on their classes.

The following is a possible solution:

```
<div>
    <a href="#id1" data-toggle="collapse">
       <div class="col-lg-12">Title</div>
    </a>
    <div class="some-class collapse ad-col-2">
       <div class="col-lg-12">Description</div>
       <div class="image"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#id2" data-toggle="collapse">
       <div class="col-lg-12">Title</div>
    </a>
    <div class="some-class collapse ad-col-2">
       <div class="col-lg-12">Description</div>
       <div class="image"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.some-class').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
        $(".image").addClass('hidden');
    });

$('.some-class').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
    $(".image").removeClass('hidden');
});
```

Comment: the accordion doesn't work because I removed the ids from the divs, add those in and it should work

Comment: but the problem that it also hides all divs with class image, but I just want it to hide class image in selected/collapsed div.

Comment: You can also do what @ams4fy suggested and "set a class to "a" and subscribe to a.class"

Answer (score 1):

Try not to subscribe on the elements by ids but by element type

```
$('a').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $(this).next().find("div.image")[0].addClass('hidden');
});

$('a').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
    $(this).next().find("div.image")[0].removeClass('hidden');
});
```

Where

```
$(this)
```

should return a pointer to the collapsed/uncollapsed element

```
next()
```

should move pointer to the next element ( div id="id1" as example)

```
find("div.image")[0]
```

will find div with class "image" and take the first found element

then you can hide the image in this block or show it without using ids

If you're using

```
$(".image").addClass('hidden');
```

this will hide all the images in all blocks (not only in that one that has been collapsed)

Comment: Good solution but this would search through all the a tags and put lots of pressure on the client.

Comment: Agreed, solution was provided for requested case, its better to set a class to "a" and subscribe to a.class